# Unable to change direction of one to many relationship in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dashboard

Whenever I try to change the direction of this relationship from "one to many", to "many to one" I get a warning.

First image: The two tables and the one to many relationship

Second image: The existing relationship parameters between the two tables

Third image: How it looks when I change the relationship and the error that I get

[image][image][image]

I have tried changing this relationship in all the normal ways but it never works. I don't get why I can't switch the direction as if can do one to many in one direction surely it can do many to one in the opposite.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)